# amazon aws billing clients per usage

Tags: amazon-web-services, billing, in-app-billing

suppose you have an app on aws and you want to charge for storage to clients for each gb they use. is there a way to get this info from amazon or collect it yourself if you are using your own aws account for this (clients have no amazon aws accounts).

for example: 10gb spent at the end of the month. have to charge it. how to figure out what to bill each of the 5 clients?

can amazon give this info? if amazon can't provide this, how to do it?
same question for storage / bandwidth and processing time.

basically do what amazon does :P

even if that is hard, how to ensure if you sell a package of 1gb / month (storage example) that the customer doesn't go over. any patterns for handling this (as in code patterns i can use)?

Comment: Is your application multi-tenant or do you have actual AWS resources allocated per client.  In other words, does each client have it's own virtual servers, S3 buckets, RDS or are your clients all sharing those resources?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Amazon provides a service that I think does exactly what you want called "DevPay" that has the ability to track and charge users S3 usage.

http://aws.amazon.com/devpay/

From the DevPay documentation:

*"Amazon DevPay is a simple-to-use online billing and account management service that makes it easy for businesses to sell applications that are built in, or run on top of, Amazon Web Services. It is designed to make running applications in the cloud and on demand easier for developers."*

If you can't use this for some reason then it's up to you track users usage within your application...

Comment: `Please note that at this time, Amazon DevPay is only available to developers in the US.` - [Amazon Web Services - Register Your Product](https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/application/registration/index.html)

Comment: Seems that they've broadened that by now: "Buyers of an Amazon DevPay application can be based anywhere in the world." -from the same faq as Alastairs comment

Comment: Nope, I still get that message.  I'm from HK.